# Erro no datetime no Django

Tags: python-3.x, json, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

Tenho essa models no Django, onde eu armazeno os dados

```
class DDoS(models.Model):
    alarm_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    platform = models.IntegerField(choices=(
        (1, "A"),
        (2, "B"),
        (3, "C"),
    ))
    target = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)
    client_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    client_name = models.TextField(null=True)
    volumetry = models.FloatField(null=True)
    date_begin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    action_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    action = models.IntegerField(choices=(
        (0, "Sem ação"),
        (1, "Blackhole"),
        (2, "TMS"),
    ))
    attack_type = models.TextField()
    mo_name = models.TextField()
    duration = models.DurationField(verbose_name="Duração")
```

Em um parte do código faço uma pagina web onde tem json que faço a coleta via power query, só que a duração vai ser assim, (00:08:55, HH:MM:SS) só que aparece esse erro **'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'**.

se eu tirar o strftime aparece assim P0DT00H03M15S a duração, não é o formato que estou querendo

```
def get_ddos_for_excel(request):
    from reports.models import DDoS
    import datetime
    from datetime import datetime
    lista_ddos = []
    for obj in DDoS.objects.all():
        lista_ddos.append({
            "ID do Alarme": obj.alarm_id,
            "Plataforma": obj.platform,
            "Target": obj.target,
            "Código do cliente": obj.client_code,
            "Nome do cliente": obj.client_name,
            "Volumetria": obj.volumetry,
            "Data de inicio": str(obj.date_begin.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')),
            "Data de fim": str(obj.date_end.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')),
            "ID da Ação": obj.action_id,
            "Ação": obj.action,
            "Tipo de Ataque": obj.attack_type,
            "MO name": obj.mo_name,
            "Duração": obj.duration.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        })
    return JsonResponse(lista_ddos, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala Lucas, tudo bem? Olha, tem algo acontecendo isso que não é exatamente essa view que você postou aqui.

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> agora = datetime.now()
>>> agora
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 14, 12, 57, 43, 205111)
>>> agora.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
'14/04/2022 12:57:43'
>>> ontem = agora - timedelta(days=1)
>>> ontem.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
'13/04/2022 12:57:43'
>>> menos_um_dia = timedelta(days=1)
>>> menos_um_dia.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    menos_um_dia.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'
>>> str(menos_um_dia)
'1 day, 0:00:00'
```

Pela sua pergunta, parece que você está tentando usar a função `strftime` em um objeto do tipo `datetime.timedelta`, isso é perigoso por alguns motivos

1. Um objeto `timedelta` é diferente de um objeto tipo `datetime` pq o `timedelta` é usado para manipulações simples de datas como subtrair dias, horas, minutos, segundos, etc. E ele não suporte o método `strftime`.
2. Provavel que em algum outro pedaço do seu código, por culpa de alguma variável você esteja retornando o timedelta ao invés do resultado da manipulação, exemplo como eu fiz na linha `ontem = agora - timedelta(days=1)` que uso o `timedelta` pra subtrair um dia.